# Restler 404 error Routes.php:431 with xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, restler

I am trying to set up a development environment on Windows with xampp 5.6.23.

I have an API I want to set up with Restler 3.0.0 so that I can browse to `http://localhost/api/cars/search?term=red` to call the `search($term)` function in the `C:\xampp\htdocs\api\cars.php` file:

```
<?php
class cars{
    public function search($term) {
    // do search...
    return $result;
    }
}
```

I also have a `C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php` set up with:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'vendor/luracast/restler/vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

Defaults::$crossOriginResourceSharing = true;

$r = new Luracast\Restler\Restler();
$r->setCompatibilityMode('2');
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat', 'JsFormat');
Luracast\Restler\Format\JsonFormat::$unEscapedUnicode = false;

$r->addAPIClass('cars');

$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources');

$r->handle(); //serve the response
```

and `C:\xampp\htdocs\api\.htdocs`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

But if I go to any URL (`/` or `/cars`) I get a 404 error:

```
<response>
 <error>
  <code>404</code>
  <message>Not Found</message>
 </error>
 <debug>
  <source>Routes.php:431 at route stage</source>
  <stages>
   <success>get</success>
   <failure>route</failure>
   <failure>negotiate</failure>
   <failure>message</failure>
  </stages>
 </debug>
</response>
```

I have tried multiple answers from SO but none have worked in my instance. I have uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and set `AllowOverride All` everywhere I could find it in `httpd.conf`. I have also tried moving my everything to `htdocs` instead of a sub folder but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have an `index()` function but only a `search()` function in your class `cars`, you need to access the URL `/cars/search/term`.

Or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: Sorry I still get a 404 XML response. My goal is to browse to `http://localhost/api/cars/search?term=red` which will call the `search()` function with the `$term` parameter equalling `red` the function then finds all red car records and returns an XML result.